# Complicated multiple select case, variable declarations, range definitions

Tags: vba, excel

I developed the code below for a budget template I'm creating from scratch.  The purpose is to populate automatically actual GL data information into my assumptions tab in the workbook. I'm using one particular month as a test.  I have set up the assumptions tab to have about 26 different sections of regional office information in order to determine an appropriate forecast.

Not all GLs are itemized. I've lumped the GLs for a particular expense (other admin) in categories. I have about 5 major categories of spend and the rest of the GLs are considered as "other".  Since the categories are not titled exactly the same as the GL accounts I've had to create a map grid on a separate tab in the workbook to link category names with different GLs.

The end goal is to:

1. Cycle through each category type on the assumptions tab for each PM region office,
2. Calculate the total amount for each spend (i.e., Evictions) by PM office plus it's cost center in another workbook,
3. Calculate the total amount for each spend of Entity code only items from that same other workbook.

The code below only cycle through and calculates the spend for Eviction GLs. I'm looking to improve the code for performance improvement, easier future maintenance(flexibility), and efficiency.  The end goal is to cycle through the different types of spend.  As of right now, my solution to do that is to repeat the variable/range declarations substituting EvictionRg for the next spend, as well as adding another *case*.

I'm afraid the code will get too long and performance may be at risk.  Any insight and guidance as how I can plan this, modify the code, etc. to help me do this will be greatly appreciated.  I've been at this for three days trying to figure it out by actually drawing a process map and other methods to help me brainstorm and by reading other posts on SO.  I'm afraid I'm at the end of my VBA knowledge.

```
Sub Try()
'Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim Wb1 As Workbook
Dim Wb2 As Workbook

Set Wb1 = Workbooks("SubModel Forecast_Other Admin v4.xlsm")
Set Wb2 = Workbooks("Feb15 PNL.xlsx")

Dim Wk4 As Worksheet
Set Wk4 = Wb1.Sheets("ASSUMPTIONS")

Dim Wk5 As Worksheet
Set Wk5 = Wb1.Sheets("Validation")

Dim Wk7 As Worksheet
Set Wk7 = Wb1.Sheets("GL Mapping")

Dim Wk1 As Worksheet
Set Wk1 = Wb2.Sheets("det")

Dim fname As String
fname = "Feb15 PNL"

With Wb1  '----submodel
    With Wk5 '---validation tab
        Dim CCCol As Long
        Dim fRowCC As Long
        Dim lRowCC As Long
        CCCol = Wk5.Cells.Find("Cost Center", lookat:=xlWhole).Column
        fRowCC = Wk5.Cells.Find("Cost Center", lookat:=xlWhole).Offset(1, 0).row
        lRowCC = Wk5.Cells.Find("Cost Center", lookat:=xlWhole).End(xlDown).row
        '---Determine cost center code column range and it's corresponding Region Office Name(ClinkRg)
        Dim CCRg As Range
        Set CCRg = Wk5.Range(Wk5.Cells(fRowCC, CCCol), Wk5.Cells(lRowCC, CCCol))
        Dim CLinkRg As Range
        Set CLinkRg = Wk5.Range(Wk5.Cells(fRowCC, CCCol).Offset(0, -1), Wk5.Cells(lRowCC, CCCol).Offset(0, -1))
    End With '----closes W5 Validation tab

    '----Grid that contains GL accounts and their category type
    With Wk7
        Dim MapGLCol As Long
        MapGLCol = Wk7.Cells.Find("GL", lookat:=xlWhole).Column
        Dim MapfRow As Long
        MapfRow = Wk7.Cells.Find("GL", lookat:=xlWhole).Offset(1, 0).row
        Dim MaplRow As Long
        MaplRow = Wk7.Cells(rows.Count, MapGLCol).End(xlUp).row
        Dim MapGLRg As Range
        Set MapGLRg = Wk7.Range(Wk7.Cells(MapfRow, MapGLCol), Wk7.Cells(MapfRow, MapGLCol))
        Dim TypeRg As Range
        Set TypeRg = Wk7.Range(Wk7.Cells(MapfRow, MapGLCol).Offset(0, -1), Wk7.Cells(MaplRow, MapGLCol).Offset(0, -1))
    End With '--closes wk7 - GL Mapping
End With '--closes Wb1 - SubModel file

'---------PNL wkb
With Wb2
    With Wk1

        'If Left(Wk2.Name, 5) = "By PM" Then
            Dim OpsCol As Long
            OpsCol = Wk1.Cells.Find("Property Manager", lookat:=xlWhole).Column
        'Else
         '   OpsCol = Wk1.Cells.Find("Submarket", lookat:=xlWhole).Column
        'End If

        Dim FRow As Long
        Dim LRow As Long
        'Dim ExpCol As Long
        Dim PropCodeCol As Long


        'Dim Expense As String
        'Expense = InputBox("Enter Expense GL")

        'to locate begining and ending row of data on PNL report
        'Identifies the column where the SubMarket names are located for lookup purposes
        'Defines the expense GL column to lookup based on the inputbox above
        FRow = Wk1.Cells.Find("66990000", lookat:=xlPart).Offset(2, 0).row
        LRow = Wk1.Cells.Find("66990000", lookat:=xlPart).End(xlDown).Offset(-1, 0).row
        'ExpCol = Wk1.Cells.Find(Expense, lookat:=xlPart).Column
        PropCodeCol = Wk1.Cells.Find("Property Code", lookat:=xlWhole).Column


        'Defines the Range of the PM
        Dim OpsRg As Range
        Set OpsRg = Wk1.Range(Wk1.Cells(FRow, OpsCol), Wk1.Cells(LRow, OpsCol))

        'Defines the Range of the Property Codes
        Dim PropCodeRg As Range
        Set PropCodeRg = Wk1.Range(Wk1.Cells(FRow, PropCodeCol), Wk1.Cells(LRow, PropCodeCol))

        'Defines the exact range of the expense column being analyzed
        'Dim ExpRg As Range
        'Set ExpRg = Wk1.Range(Wk1.Cells(FRow, ExpCol), Wk1.Cells(LRow, ExpCol))

        'Defining range for GLs under Other Admin
        Dim GLRow As Long
        Dim BegGLCol As Long
        Dim EndGLCol As Long
        GLRow = Wk1.Cells.Find("66550000", lookat:=xlPart).row
        BegGLCol = Wk1.Cells.Find("66550000", lookat:=xlPart).Column
        EndGLCol = Wk1.Cells.Find("66990000", lookat:=xlPart).Column

        Dim GLRg As Range
        Set GLRg = Wk1.Range(Wk1.Cells(GLRow, BegGLCol), Wk1.Cells(GLRow, EndGLCol))

        '----Find All GL accounts in WB1 Wk5 Validation Tab range TypeRg categorized as Evictions($)
        '----Then Look up each GL account in the row with all the GLs in the current workbook PNL and Wk1
        '----------Set that up as TempCell
        '----------Set the range for the entire column of data for each GL and consolidate as one range 'EvictionRg'
        '----------Purpose of this is to set up one range for all GL accounts categorized as Eviction GL accoutns
        Dim c As Range
        For Each c In TypeRg
            If c = "Evictions ($)" Then
                Dim TempCell As Range
                Set TempCell = GLRg.Find(c.Offset(0, 1).Value, lookat:=xlWhole)
                'MsgBox (TempCell)

                Dim EvictionRg As Range
                If EvictionRg Is Nothing Then
                    Set EvictionRg = Wk1.Range(Wk1.Cells(FRow, TempCell.Column), Wk1.Cells(LRow, TempCell.Column))
                Else
                    Set EvictionRg = Union(EvictionRg, Wk1.Range(Wk1.Cells(FRow, TempCell.Column), Wk1.Cells(LRow, TempCell.Column)))
                End If

            End If
        Next c
        '---Sum up all the amounts under all the GL eviction accounts and set them as "z"
        Dim z As Double
        z = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(EvictionRg)

    '---Define Ranges for All Entities, Cost Centers, Entities Not Cost Centers

    'Define the range on the Property PNL workbook all items booked under an entity
    Dim AllEntRg As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In OpsRg
      If cell = "" Then
          If AllEntRg Is Nothing Then
              Set AllEntRg = Wk1.Cells(cell.row, PropCodeCol)
          Else
              Set AllEntRg = Union(AllEntRg, Wk1.Cells(cell.row, PropCodeCol))
          End If
      End If
    Next cell

    'Define the range of the property PNL workbook that are Entity codes that are NOT Cost Center Codes
    '---Entity Codes and Cost Center Codes are within the AllEntRg
    '---Create a new range in the Eviction GL Range that intersects
    '---------the rows of the entity only codes and the eviction GL columns
    With AllEntRg
    Dim EntityRg As Range
    Dim cl As Range
    For Each cl In AllEntRg
            If CCRg.Find(cl.Value, lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then
                Dim cl2 As Range
                For Each cl2 In EvictionRg '------extra
                If cl2.row = cl.row Then '------extra
                    If EntityRg Is Nothing Then
                        Set EntityRg = cl2
                    Else
                        Set EntityRg = Union(EntityRg, cl2)
                    End If
                End If
                Next cl2
            End If
    Next cl
    'MsgBox (EntityRg.Address)
    Dim v As Double
    v = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(EntityRg)
    End With

    'With AllEntRg
    'Dim CostCRg As Range
    'Dim r As Range
    'For Each r In AllEntRg
     '       If Not CCRg.Find(r.Value, lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then
     '           Dim cl3 As Range
     '           For Each cl3 In EvictionRg
     '           If cl3.row = r.row Then
     '               If CostCRg Is Nothing Then
     '                   Set CostCRg = cl3
     '               Else
     '                   Set CostCRg = Union(CostCRg, cl3)
     '               End If
     '           End If
      '          Next cl3
     '       End If
    'Next r
    'End With
    'MsgBox (CostCRg.Address)

    'Define cell ranges for regional PM offices that contain more than one cost center ocde
    With AllEntRg
        If Not AllEntRg.Find("cahied", lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then
            Dim n As Range
            Set n = AllEntRg.Find("cahied", lookat:=xlWhole)
        End If
        'MsgBox (n.Address)

        If Not AllEntRg.Find("cahrvr", lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then
            Dim n2 As Range
            Set n2 = AllEntRg.Find("cahrvr", lookat:=xlWhole)
            'MsgBox (n2.Address)
        End If

        If Not AllEntRg.Find("atlnw", lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then
            Dim an1 As Range
            Set an1 = AllEntRg.Find("atlnw", lookat:=xlWhole)
            'MsgBox (an1.Address)
        End If

        If Not AllEntRg.Find("atln", lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then
            Dim an2 As Range
            Set an2 = AllEntRg.Find("atln", lookat:=xlWhole)
            'MsgBox (an2.Address)
        End If

        If Not AllEntRg.Find("atlse", lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then
            Dim ae1 As Range
            Set ae1 = AllEntRg.Find("atlse", lookat:=xlWhole)
            'MsgBox (ae1.Address)
        End If

        If Not AllEntRg.Find("atle", lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then
            Dim ae2 As Range
            Set ae2 = AllEntRg.Find("atle", lookat:=xlWhole)
            'MsgBox (ae2.Address)
        End If

        If Not AllEntRg.Find("atlsw", lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then
            Dim as1 As Range
            Set as1 = AllEntRg.Find("atlsw", lookat:=xlWhole)
            'MsgBox (as1.Address)
        End If

        If Not AllEntRg.Find("atls", lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then
            Dim as2 As Range
            Set as2 = AllEntRg.Find("atls", lookat:=xlWhole)
            'MsgBox (as2.Address)
        End If
    End With

        '---Create a new range in the Eviction GL Range that intersects
        '---------the rows of the specific cost center codes and the eviction GL columns
        If Not n Is Nothing Or Not n2 Is Nothing Then
            Dim n3 As Range
            For Each n3 In EvictionRg
               If n3.row = n.row Or n3.row = n2.row Then
                    Dim InlandRg As Range
                    If InlandRg Is Nothing Then
                        Set InlandRg = n3
                    Else
                        Set InlandRg = Union(InlandRg, n3)
                    End If
                End If
            Next n3
        End If
                Dim n3v As Double
                n3v = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(InlandRg)


        If Not an1 Is Nothing Or Not an2 Is Nothing Then
            Dim an3 As Range
            For Each an3 In EvictionRg
               If an3.row = an1.row Or an3.row = an2.row Then
                    Dim ATLNrg As Range
                    If ATLNrg Is Nothing Then
                        Set ATLNrg = an3
                    Else
                        Set ATLNrg = Union(ATLNrg, an3)
                    End If
                End If
            Next an3
        End If
                Dim an3v As Double
                an3v = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(ATLNrg)


        If Not ae1 Is Nothing Or Not ae2 Is Nothing Then
            Dim ae3 As Range
            For Each ae3 In EvictionRg
               If ae3.row = ae1.row Or ae3.row = ae2.row Then
                    Dim ATLErg As Range
                    If ATLErg Is Nothing Then
                        Set ATLErg = ae3
                    Else
                        Set ATLErg = Union(ATLErg, ae3)
                    End If
                End If
            Next ae3
        End If
                Dim ae3v As Double
                ae3v = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(ATLErg)

        If Not as1 Is Nothing Or Not as2 Is Nothing Then
            Dim as3 As Range
            For Each as3 In EvictionRg
               If as3.row = as1.row Or as3.row = as2.row Then
                    Dim ATLSrg As Range
                    If ATLSrg Is Nothing Then
                        Set ATLSrg = as3
                    Else
                        Set ATLSrg = Union(ATLSrg, as3)
                    End If
                End If
            Next as3
        End If
                Dim as3v As Double
                as3v = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(ATLSrg)

    End With '---closes Wk1 (PNL report)
End With '--closes wb2


''--------Cycle through the different PM regional office section (column) in assumptions tab
'---------Identify where Evictions ($) is located
'---------calculate total eviction GL amounts for each section (by Entity code only, by PM + cost center code)

With Wb1
With Wk4

    Wk4.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=2

    Dim dateRow As Long
    dateRow = Wk4.Cells.Find("ACT", lookat:=xlWhole).Offset(1, 0).row

    Dim fRow2 As Long
    Dim AssumCol As Long
    Dim lRow2 As Long
    fRow2 = Wk4.Cells.Find("Global Assumptions", lookat:=xlWhole).row
    AssumCol = Wk4.Cells.Find("Global Assumptions", lookat:=xlWhole).Column
    lRow2 = Wk4.Cells(rows.Count, AssumCol).End(xlUp).row

    Dim AssumptionRg As Range
    Set AssumptionRg = Wk4.Range(Wk4.Cells(fRow2, AssumCol), Wk4.Cells(lRow2, AssumCol))


    Dim r2 As Range
    Dim isItem As Boolean

        For Each r2 In AssumptionRg
            Select Case r2
                Case "Evictions ($)"
                    isItem = True
                    Dim PM As Range
                    Set PM = r2.End(xlUp)
                        '---If PM Label is Entity Level, Inland Empire or is one of the Atlanta PMs then
                        '-----IF Entity Level, the sum up the Entity Range for the Evictions
                        '-----IF Inland Empire, sum up Inland Empire properties and Inland Empire Cost Center entries
                        '-----IF Atlanta, the sum up Atlanta PMs and their cost center entries individually
                        If PM = "Tie-Out To Actuals" Or PM = "Entity Level Assumptions" _
                        Or PM = "Inland Empire" Or PM = "Atlanta East" _
                        Or PM = "Atlanta North" Or PM = "Atlanta South" Then

                            If PM = "Tie-Out To Actuals" Then
                                Wk4.Cells(r2.row, 4) = z
                            End If

                            If PM = "Entity Level Assumptions" Then
                                Wk4.Cells(r2.row, 4) = v
                            End If

                            If PM = "Inland Empire" Then
                                    Wk4.Cells(r2.row, 4).Formula = _
                                    "=SUMPRODUCT(('[" & fname & ".xlsx]det'!" & OpsRg.Address & "=" & PM.Address & ")*'[" & fname & ".xlsx]det'!" & EvictionRg.Address & ")" _
                                    & "+" & n3v
                                    Wk4.Cells(r2.row, 4).Value = Wk4.Cells(r2.row, 4).Value
                            End If

                            If PM = "Atlanta East" Then
                                Wk4.Cells(r2.row, 4).Formula = _
                                "=SUMPRODUCT(('[" & fname & ".xlsx]det'!" & OpsRg.Address & "=" & PM.Address & ")*'[" & fname & ".xlsx]det'!" & EvictionRg.Address & ")" _
                                & "+" & ae3v
                            End If

                            If PM = "Atlanta North" Then
                                Wk4.Cells(r2.row, 4).Formula = _
                                "=SUMPRODUCT(('[" & fname & ".xlsx]det'!" & OpsRg.Address & "=" & PM.Address & ")*'[" & fname & ".xlsx]det'!" & EvictionRg.Address & ")" _
                                & "+" & an3v
                            End If

                            If PM = "Atlanta South" Then
                                Wk4.Cells(r2.row, 4).Formula = _
                                "=SUMPRODUCT(('[" & fname & ".xlsx]det'!" & OpsRg.Address & "=" & PM.Address & ")*'[" & fname & ".xlsx]det'!" & EvictionRg.Address & ")" _
                                & "+" & as3v
                            End If

                        Else

                            Dim CCCodeRow As Long
                            Dim CCCodeCol As Long
                            CCCodeRow = CLinkRg.Find(PM.Value, lookat:=xlWhole).Offset(0, 1).row
                            CCCodeCol = CLinkRg.Find(PM.Value, lookat:=xlWhole).Offset(0, 1).Column

                            If Wk5.Cells(CCCodeRow, CCCodeCol).Value = "None" Then
                                Wk4.Cells(r2.row, 4).Formula = _
                                "=SUMPRODUCT(('[" & fname & ".xlsx]det'!" & OpsRg.Address & "=" & PM.Address & ")*'[" & fname & ".xlsx]det'!" & EvictionRg.Address & ")"
                            Else
                                Wk4.Cells(r2.row, 4).Formula = _
                                "=SUMPRODUCT(('[" & fname & ".xlsx]det'!" & OpsRg.Address & "=" & PM.Address & ")*'[" & fname & ".xlsx]det'!" & EvictionRg.Address & ")" _
                                & "+SUMPRODUCT(('[" & fname & ".xlsx]det'!" & PropCodeRg.Address & "=" & "Validation!" & Wk5.Cells(CCCodeRow, CCCodeCol).Address & ")*'[" & fname & ".xlsx]det'!" & EvictionRg.Address & ")"
                            End If
                        End If
           End Select
        Next r2

    Set r2 = Nothing
    Set Wk4 = Nothing
End With '---closes assumptions tab
End With '---workbook2
'Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: If the code is working, this sounds more suited for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Thank you Comintern.  I didn't know Code Review existed.  I will look in to that as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whew, that is quite the read!  Although I agree with Comintern, I do see a pretty simple solution to trimming up your code, and making it easier to maintain.

I don't see a single function in the entire thing.  If you're writing scripts that long, and not using them, you need to start... They'll change your life.

Lets take a simple block that I see repeated several (8) times.  Note that I see several much larger blocks that are repeated throughout, but this one will be easy to learn on.

```
If Not AllEntRg.Find("atlsw", lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then
    Dim as1 As Range
    Set as1 = AllEntRg.Find("atlsw", lookat:=xlWhole)
End If
```

I only see three things that change from if to if in this part of the code, 2 on the input side are a range and a string, and it outputs a range if conditions are met.  So you write a function like this, and place it somewhere in any module in the same workbook.

```
Public Function DefMultiCCPMRange(rngSearchRange as range, strSearchString as string)as range
    If Not AllEndRg.Find(strSearchString, lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then
        set DefMultiCCPMRange = rngSearchRange.Find(strSearchString, Lookat:=xlWhole)
    End If
End Function
```

Now instead of rewriting this over and over.

```
If Not AllEntRg.Find("atlsw", lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then
    Dim as1 As Range
    Set as1 = AllEntRg.Find("atlsw", lookat:=xlWhole)
End If
```

You write this over and over.

```
Dim as1 as Range
set as1 = DefMultiCCPMRange(AllEndRg,"atlsw")
```

Also the lifetime of the variables that are used in the function, ends when the function ends, so your not storing every variable you use in memory for the entire duration of runtime.

That should take you a long way if you play with it.

I would also look into Arrays, Collections, and Dictionary items.  They'll change your life too once you see where their power really lies.  You could get creative and instead of declaring and setting that range 8 times, you could do a for loop, and put them all in one object named for the CC Code.

```
Dim arrCCCodes(3) as string 'change to arrCCCodes(7) for your 8 codes
arrCCCodes(0) = "cahied"
arrCCCodes(1) = "cahrvr"
arrCCCodes(2) = "atlnw"
arrCCCodes(3) = "atln"
'etc...
'add a reference to Microsoft scripting runtime

Dim odicCCRanges as New Dictionary

For i = 0 to UBound(arrCCCodes)
    odicCCRanges.Add arrCCCodes(i), DefMultiCCPMRange(AllEndRg, arrCCCodes(i))
next
```

This will give you a dictionary object with 4 ranges in it (would be 8 in your actual code), not to mention lose a couple pages of code.  You would call the values in the range like `odicCCRanges("cahied").Item(1)` or `odicCCRanges(arrCCCodes(0)).Item(1)`.  Here's where it adds to your project lifetime.  If you need to add a new CC, you just change the `arrCCCodes` declaration to include one more item, then add it below, and the rest of our code will automatically pick it up, run the define ranges function, and add it to the dictionary.

Your code doesn't look all that bad, your testing for nulls, and declaring your vars, all good stuff. It's just all series scripted. Try stepping through your code, and watching the locals window in the VBA IDE.  Particularly expand a range node after its set.  It'll blow your mind what is actually in a Range Object.

Comment: Incredible!  Thanks!  I spend a portion of my mornings at work reading through Stackoverflow.  I haven't played around with functions, arrays, collections, dictionaries which is why I mentioned I think I have reached my VBA knowledge.  Thank you for the examples.  I will take this and play with it to learn and see what I can develop.  I appreciate the insight.  Hopefully I can pick this up and really improve my coding to automate my work and those within my accounting/finance department. Your explanation seems logical so I will give it a go.  I will post back with positive results or question

Comment: No problem at all!  This is my favorite stage to help in.  This is where your programming abilities start to grow exponentially.

Answer (score 0):

You obviously have a lot of time invested in this but I really think you are over complicating things. Since all your code is doing is building ranges and then summing them I'm thinking you could do this with array formulas.